# Has the review job stopped working properly?

Tags: bug, review

Reviews usually come in to the sites at around the same time. For FPs that is at the next multiple of 5 minute after the post was posted. However, since last night (~19:00 GMT) I have noticed that this doesn't seem to be happening anymore. For a recent example on SFF [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208007/58193) never went to the FP queue despite being eligible.

Has something changed with regards to the review job or is there a bug preventing normal procedures? And if something has changed, why? These sorts of reviews need to be handled as soon as possible.

Comment: That got closed after 11 minutes, doesn't it normally take about 15 minutes for them to appear on the queues?

Comment: @PeterJ Not for FPs, FPs come in anywhere between 0-5mins usually. LAs, LQPs, ROVs and CVs come in, in ~15 mins.

Comment: I've also noticed that chat room feeds are no longer posting in SFF's main chatroom [TREU](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) which is probably related.

Comment: @PeterJ In either case all reviews are affected not just FPs, see the [timeline here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/207966/timeline) from yesterday where the FP took ~13 mins and the LQP ~1 hour.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325811/reputation-sync-from-main-to-meta-is-stalled. (The devs are looking into it)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Maybe, maybe not. About 2 hours ago things seem to have returned to normal, the Feeds finally came in and reviews seem to be back to normal. At least for the time being anyway. Though I will note my meta rep hasn't caught up with my main rep yet.