# Reputation sync from main to meta is stalled

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, per-site-meta

It appears that updating the reputation shown for users on per-site meta sites stopped working sometime yesterday.  (I think I have it narrowed down to a span of a few hours.)  Here are the data points I've observed:

- On Mi Yodeya, an [upvote I received yesterday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio?tab=reputation) has not yet been reflected [on meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio).  This made me curious so I looked for more.
- [Another user on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4794/y-e-z?tab=reputation) also shows a [meta gap](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4794/y-e-z) of more than the reputation earned today.
- It's not specific to that site.  [This user on Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/25517/liquid?tab=reputation) also shows a [meta gap](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25517/liquid).
- Can we narrow it down at all?  [This user](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14704/galastel?tab=reputation)'s [meta profile](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14704/galastel) reflects some but not all rep earned yesterday.  The last 15 points earned yesterday (and the 10 earned today) are not counted, so the syncing probably stopped working (on that site) between 13:46 and 17:15 yesterday.

Comment: Hmmm, problem seems more widespread than first glance. I'd also just noticed that users scheduled for deletion are not actually being deleted. That entire scheduled task might be malfunctioning.

Comment: We are looking.

Comment: @animuson Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325793/has-the-review-job-stopped-working-properly

Comment: Just to add in the information from my above linked meta. Reviews stopped coming in when they should and Feeds in chatrooms stopped working. ~2 hours ago they booted back up and things started working normally again. However, my meta rep is yet to sync with my main rep so the issue may or may not be the same.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard might be related, though I notice that question is from last year and the main/meta sync I reported worked until yesterday.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard That's a completely separate issue not related to the current issue of the scheduled tasks just not running at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report, the scheduled job got very angry and in an inconsistent state. We're investigating why that's the case, but you should find everything is synced up now.

Comment: Is this the same as what was [happening here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325793/345161) with reviews and chat feeds?

Comment: Topic at next team meeting: anger management for scripts. :-)