# Review queues aren't being populated

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

It looks like there's a bug in the review queues, which causes them not be filled. It's most visible in the [First Posts review queue on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) – ([screenshot for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz13y.png)); all items younger than 0:00 UTC are review audits, but I have reason to believe queues all across the network have gone silent. E.g. if you look at today's stats for a couple of queues - only two reviews for queues which are normally much more active:

- [First Posts on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats)
- [First Posts on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats)

Comment: ... and as we speak, somebody hit the reset button and queues are full again. Still, maybe someone might want to explain what went wrong.

Comment: see also: [The triage queue is marked for me in red for hours, but when I open it it's empty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382386/839601) at MSO

Comment: same issue as of mine :)

Comment: Database glitch, most likely... maybe due to bad build... it's not really rare.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325793/has-the-review-job-stopped-working-properly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. The scheduler has some minor issues and backed up. Things should be back in working order now.

Comment: please consider updating [this cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382386/839601) at MSO